# What's the order in the virtual key code array?

Tags: c#, arrays, keyboard, key

I need to know what's the order of the virtual key code array after the calling of the `GetKeyboardState` method.

Reminder :

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);
```

In fact, I need to change the Menu, LMenu, RMenu, Control, LControl and RControl value to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit obvious, they are ordered by their virtual key code.  Some possibly helpful code:

```
var keys = new byte[256];
if (!GetKeyboardState(keys)) throw new Win32Exception();
keys[(int)Keys.Menu] = keys[(int)Keys.LMenu] = keys[(int)Keys.RMenu] = 0;
keys[(int)Keys.ControlKey] = keys[(int)Keys.LControlKey] = keys[(int)Keys.RControlKey] = 0;
if (!SetKeyboardState(keys)) throw new Win32Exception();
```

Note that the pinvoke declaration is missing the required SetLastError = true.  This is a bug at the pinvoke.net web site, I couldn't fix it.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work. Just note that the Keys need a int cast to been use as array index.